# Doctrine2 lifecycle callbacks in base class?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

In Doctrine2 is it possible to invoke lifecycle callbacks in a base class, which all entities inherit from.

Something like this http://pastie.org/2650901

The problem is that `validationCheck()` method doesn't get invoked when I persist or update an entity.

Also, I tried making the base class `@MappedSuperclass`, but then it breaks all further inheritance, and that is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it working, my mistake.
Here is the solution, if anyone else stumbles on the same issue.

Base class has to have a `@MappedSuperclass` and `@HasLifecycleCallbacks` notation.

Entity class, if uses further inheritance, has to be `abstract`.

http://pastie.org/2661834

Comment: Basically you mean, having a separate class for the lifecycle callbacks? We have an admin class that extends the abstract user class, but does not retrieve the callbacks.